# Make Wordpress-blog totally private to logged out visitors?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm building a Wordpress-site, where user needs to log in before access to the blog itself. For now, I've used this:

```
add_action('wp_head','foofunc');
function foofunc() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) die();
}
```

However, this way I cannot redirect the user to another url, as output has already started. Is there any way to redirect not-logged-in users to an url?

I would user `init` but that redirects users in wp-admin too.

Martti Laine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "init" handler together with is_admin() to check if the user is already in the admin panel or not:

```
add_action('init','foofunc');
function foofunc() {
    $isLoginPage = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "wp-login.php") !== false;   
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin() &&  !$isLoginPage) {
        header( 'Location: http://yourdomain.com/login' ) ;
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm making it a plugin, so it needs to be done via `add_action`.

Comment: So `add_action("init", "foofunc")` would be the solution. If it causes problems with wp-admin, just use is_admin() to detect if the user is already in the admin panel or not. I'm going to update my answer with the new code.

Comment: Actually this snippet prevents me from logging in at all. Any idea of how to fix that?

Comment: Ok then you need to check whether the current page is the login page, and, in that case, don't do the redirection. You can use `REQUEST_URI` to find the current URL and check if it contains "wp-login". I have updated the example code.

Answer (score 2):

This was a turnkey solution that worked right out of the box for us.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-privacy-options/

Answer (score 1):

1. you could use the s2member plugin. It creates 4 user levels the first level is for free users. When you create a page, you can pick a S2Member userlevel requirement for that pages.
2. http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/require-login-for-wordpress-pages/ create a page-password-protect template that follows the format in that link. Apply the template to pages you want password protected.
3. you could write a function that checks to see if a user is logged in on pages using *is_user_logged_in()*, *is_admin()* and *is_page()* and then redirects. make that function an action. Then hook that action into *init*. (I'm a little fuzzy if init is the right hook, but your redirect won't happen if any output has been sent to the screen)

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest implementation:

```
if( (!is_user_logged_in()) && ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] !== 'wp-login.php')  ) {
  wp_redirect('http://anothersite.com');
}
```

Can be placed as is in functions.php