# Wordpress Redirect Home to another URL if not logged in

Tags: wordpress

is there any way to redirect web visitor to another URL, but when admin is login or visit wp-admin it will stay in current URL?

for example, when user visit abc.com it will redirect to xyz.com
when user visit abc.com/wp-admin or logged in, it still open abc.com

my code so far on function.php:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_visitor' );

function redirect_visitor() 
{
    if( !is_user_logged_in()  )
    {
        wp_redirect( site_url( 'xyz.com' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
redirect_visitor()
```

The problem is the code still redirect wp-admin to xyz.com so i cannot login.

Comment: closed. Finally found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010694/make-wordpress-blog-totally-private-to-logged-out-visitors

Answer (score 0):

you can use it

```
add_action( 'wp', 'redirect_visitor', 9999 );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_visitor', 9999 );
function redirect_visitor() 
{
    if( !is_user_logged_in()  )
    {
        wp_redirect( 'http://example.com' );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing happened when I tried this function.

Comment: I changed my code, please check it now

Comment: it still same. nothing happened. when i visit as a guest, still open the abc.com

Comment: could you please share website link and screenshot where you are adding this code

Comment: I'm adding at function.php and my website is orthopaedia.co.id

Comment: I added priority in this code, please check it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247300/discussion-between-ashok-kumawat-and-cross-vander).